# Zero padded-OFDM signal?

Tags: fft, dft, ofdm

Why do we need **2N-FFT** at the receiver when we want to demodulate **ZP-OFDM** signal ?

Comment: Is that question still active? I can give the answer, but dont want to put the effort, if it wont be read anyway.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé: No matter if the OP is still interested, if you think that the question and its answer can be valuable for other users and future visitors of this site, you should consider providing an answer. Even if your answer will not get accepted, you can still gain upvotes if it is considered informative and well-written.